# Julia language. How to beat vectorized operations?

Tags: performance, for-loop, vectorization, julia

It is said that Julia for-loops are as fast as vectorized operations and even faster (if they are used properly). 
I have two pieces of code. The idea is to find a sample statistic for a given 0-1 sequence, which is x (in these two examples i'm trying to find a sum, but there are more complicated examples, i'm just trying to understand a general meaning of performance pitfalls in my code). The first looks like:

```
S = 2 * sum(x) - n
s_obs_new = abs(S) / sqrt(2 * n)
pval = erfc(s_obs_new)
```

and the second is something "naive" and classical:

```
S = 0
for i in eachindex(x)
    S += x[i]
end
S = 2 * S - n
s_obs_new = abs(S) / sqrt(2 * n)
pval = erfc(s_obs_new)
```

Using @benchmark i've found that the running time of the first example is about 11.8 ms, and for the second is 38 ms.

This example is of very importance for me, because there are a lot of other places, where vectorization isn't possible, so i want to do computations in devectorized "manner" as fast as in vectorized.

Is there any ideas why devectorized code is likely 4x times slower than vectorized? The type stability is OK, there is no unnecessary big memory allocations and etc.

The code for the first function is:

```
function frequency_monobit_test1( x :: Array{Int8, 1}, n = 0)
# count 1 and 0 in sequence, we want the number
# of 1's and 0's to be approximately the same
# reccomendation n >= 100
# decision Rule(at 1% level): if pval < 0.01 -> non-random
if (n == 0)
    n = length(x)
end
S = 2 * sum(x) - n
s_obs_new = abs(S) / sqrt(2 * n)
pval = erfc(s_obs_new)
return pval
```

The second is:

```
function frequency_monobit_test2( x :: Array{Int8, 1}, n = 0)
# count 1 and 0 in sequence, we want the number
# of 1's and 0's to be approximately the same
# reccomendation n >= 100
# decision Rule(at 1% level): if pval < 0.01 -> non-random
if (n == 0)
    n = length(x)
end
S = 0
@inbounds for i in eachindex(x)
    S += x[i]
end
S = 2 * S - n
s_obs_new = abs(S) / sqrt(2 * n)
pval = erfc(s_obs_new)
return pval
```

Comment: First, the official [Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/) are important to read

Comment: Another thing to try is to put `@inbounds @simd` in front of the `for` statement

Comment: Please show us the actual code you run to get the benchmarks.

Comment: Can you provide some input to test the code on? How can one generate `x`? Also, if you want to time the code properly, you should use https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl , don't just use `@time` in global scope.

Comment: The only difference between your two code snippets is that you call `sum` in the first, and manually accumulate in a loop in the second. They should be equally fast, if you use `@inbounds`. Also, make sure that you initialize `S` to the correct type. Is `x` integer or float? Best to initialize with `S = zero(eltype(x))` instead of `S = 0`. And use `BenchmarkTools.jl`, as I mentioned.

Comment: Because we don't have your code we can't say for certain but you [shouldn't benchmark your code in global scope](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables-1). Also in julia v0.6 you [don't have to use loops any more](https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots)

Comment: Hello everyone.
1. In order to test a performance i firstly create a new variable
`const x = Array{Int8}(rand([0,1], 2^25))`
I'm only interested in testing boolean vectors, so i use 8bit integer. I use word "const" for type-stability.
2. Then i'm testing my two functions using @benchmark. So it looks like
'@benchmark foo1(x)
@benchmark foo2(x)'
3. I will add the full code to my question. I didn't do it before because  i thought it could hide the idea of what they are doing.

PS: sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a curious case. There seems to be a performance problem when accumulating `Int8`s in an `Int64` variable.

Let's try these functions:

```
using SpecialFunctions, BenchmarkTools

function frequency_monobit_test1(x, n=length(x))
    S = sum(x)
    return erfc(abs(2S - n) / sqrt(2n))
end

function frequency_monobit_test3(typ::Type{<:Integer}, x, n=length(x))
    S = zero(typ)
    for i in eachindex(x)
        @inbounds S += x[i]
    end
    return erfc(abs(2S - n) / sqrt(2n))
end
```

Initializing some vectors

```
N = 2^25;
x64 = rand(0:1, N);
x8 = rand(Int8[0, 1], N);
xB = rand(Bool, N);
xb = bitrand(N);
```

Benchmarking:

For `Int64` input:

```
julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test1($x64)
  17.540 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.10302739916042186

julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test3(Int64, $x64)
  17.796 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.10302739916042186

julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test3(Int32, $x64)
  892.715 ms (67106751 allocations: 1023.97 MiB)
0.10302739916042186
```

We see that `sum` and an explicit loop are equally fast, and that initializing with an `Int32` is a bad idea.

For `Int32` input:

```
julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test1($x32)
  9.137 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.2386386867682374

julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test3(Int64, $x32)
  8.839 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.2386386867682374

julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test3(Int32, $x32)
  7.274 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.2386386867682374
```

`sum` and loop are similar in speed. Accumulating into `Int32` saves a bit of time.

`Int8` input:

```
julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test1($x8)
  5.681 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.16482999123032094

julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test3(Int64, $x8)
  19.517 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.16482999123032094

julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test3(Int32, $x8)
  4.815 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.16482999123032094
```

Explicit loop if slightly faster when accumulating into an `Int32`, but holy cow! what's going on with `Int64`? That is super slow!

What about `Bool`?

```
julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test1($xB)
  9.627 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.7728544347518309

julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test3(Int64, $xB)
  9.629 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.7728544347518309

julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test3(Int32, $xB)
  4.815 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.7728544347518309
```

Loop and `sum` have same speed but, accumulating into `Int32` saves half the time.

Now we'll try a `BitArray`:

```
julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test1($xb)
  259.044 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.7002576522570715

julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test3(Int64, $xb)
  19.423 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.7002576522570715

julia> @btime frequency_monobit_test3(Int32, $xb)
  19.430 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.7002576522570715
```

So, `sum` on a `BitArray` is crazy fast, because you can perform chunked additions, but extracting single elements in a loop has some overhead.

Conclusions:

- You can get similar or better performance with a loop than with `sum`, except for `BitArray`s which is a very special case.
- If you know the length of your array, and know that `Int32` is enough to hold your sum, then that's a time saver.
- There is something very strange going on when accumulating `Int8`s into an `Int64`. I don't know why the performance is so bad.
- If you are only interested in zeros and ones, use an array of `Bool`s, not of `Int8`s, and possibly accumulate into an `Int32`.
- `BitArray`s can be super fast in certain cases.
- `sum` on a vector of `Int8`s is strangely fast, twice as fast as `sum(::Vector{Bool})`.